# How is countability defined within ZF set theory?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was having this doubt regarding how countability is defined *within* ZF set theory, in particular in relation with the Skolem-Löwenheim downward and upward theorems. I know 'countability' for a set is often defined as the existence of a bijection between its elements and $\mathbb{N}$, but how is this expressed in the language of ZF set theory? How does one speak of 'bijections,' for example? My concerns regarding this are also in relation to Skolem's paradox: I 'understand' that countability as seen from outside and from inside a model is distinct, and that countable models of ZF *can* exist (by DSL) due to them (in very informal words) being so 'poor' as to 'miss out' on some actually-existing bijections outside the model (this is the explanation van Dalen provides in his *Logic and Structure*).

Now, the concerns which make me seek the in-model notion of countability are the following: One can, given an appropriate language (say a language of identity $\mathscr{L}$ of type $\langle0; \ 0; \ 0\rangle$), define statements $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$ to effectively account for finite cardinality of a model and verify whether it possesses 'at least $n$ elements' or 'at most $n$ elements' respectively. One can also verify that any model of $\lbrace \lambda_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is infinite.
Now, I do not know whether this is possible, but, depending on how one defines 'countability' (and 'uncountability') within ZF, could one write a statement analogous to $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$ to mean (outside the model) 'has $\aleph_0$ elements'?
If so, I suppose that, say, $\mathbb{N}$ could model such a statement, but here is where my concern arises:
According to USL, if our statement $\varphi$ (of outside-model meaning 'has $\aleph_0$ elements') was expressed in a language of cardinality $\kappa$, then, if there exists some model $\mathfrak{A} \in \text{Mod}(\varphi)$ of cardinality $\lambda \ge \kappa$, there must exist models of $\varphi$ of *any* cardinality $\mu \gt \lambda$.

Now, as the language $\varphi$ (in case of existing) would be expressed in would have cardinality $\ge \aleph_0$, and $\mathbb{N}$ as a (likely) model of $\varphi$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$, would this not mean, then, that there exist models of cardinality $\gt \aleph_0$ that model 'has $\aleph_0$ elements'?
I suppose some possible, limiting facts would be that (a) $\varphi$ might not be expressable in the language of ZF (in which case, how are countability and uncountability defined *inside* ZF?), or (b) the language $\varphi$ is expressable in has cardinality $\gt \aleph_0$ (in which case no model of actual $\aleph_0$ cardinality would have the appropriate type to model it, i.e., it would have no models).

I thank in advance any responses or help in clarifying my confussions surrounding this much interesting topic.

Comment: you need to have a blank line to have a paragraph break. I edited to what I hope your intentions were.

Comment: Bijections are functions... functions are sets of ordered pairs. Ordered pairs can be implemented in many ways, most commonly $(a,b) := \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}.$ So $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$ if it is a set of ordered pairs, each with first coordinate in $A$ and second coordinate in $B$ and such that $\forall x\in A\;\exists ! y\in B \;(x,y)\in f$ and $\forall y\in B \;\exists ! x\in A \;(x,y)\in f.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Functions (and in particular bijections) are definable in terms of ordered pairs, i.e., sets, and so I suppose talk of bijections could be rewritten in those terms. Does that mean that there exists a such statement (or set of statements) that determine countability (or uncountability) within the model? I know the set of $\lambda_n$ statements can be utilized as a way to determine if a set is infinite, but is there a way to further determine its infinity's size (i.e., whether its cardinality is $\aleph_0$ or whether it is greater)?

Comment: Within the model or of the model? There's certainly a ZF-definable predicate "$x$ is countably infinite", which is just "there is a bijection between $x$ and $\omega$" with a suitable definition of $\omega.$ But that's quite different from the question of whether there's a sentence that a model (of ZF) satisfies if and only if it's countably infinite. There is not: that would flagrantly violate the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem.

Comment: Or I guess you could also mean a predicate "$x$ is externally countably infinite" which holds of an element $x$ of any model if and only if $x$ has (externally) countably-infinitely-many elements. Again, Lowenheim-Skolem considerations show there is no such predicate.

Comment: I apologize for my perhaps confusing wording, I am just beggining to learn about logic and there are some things I may not have the firmest grasp on yet. What I meant is: is there a sentence (or set of sentences) in the language of ZF (I assume of type $\langle2; \ 0; \ 0\rangle$) that a model of ZF satisfies iff it is (externally) countable. It might not even need be the language of ZF, just if there is any definable set of sentences such that its language-appropriate models are countably infinite. When you say Löwenheim-Skolem, do you mean their upward and downward theorems in conjunction?

Comment: What I believe you are saying is that, within the language of ZF, one can define a predicate $P(x)$ meaning (externally) "$x$ is countably infinite" such that, given a structure $\mathfrak{A} = \langle A; \ \in\rangle$, for example, $\mathfrak{A}$ models $\exists x \ P(x)$ iff an element of $\mathfrak{A}$ is infinitely countable. What cannot be done due to LS (could you explain why exactly?) is a sentence (set of sentences) that, if modelled, imply the model's countably infinite cardinality? This because due to USL there would then exist higher-cardinality models of said sentence?

Comment: No, the first predicate I mentioned defines countability internally, not externally. In answer to your question, no, there is no such sentence or set of sentences, in the language of set theory or otherwise (provided we are only talking about first-order sentences). This is due to the USL, which implies if any set of first-order sentences has a countably infinite model, then it has models of higher cardinality.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the reason why. I believe my confusion stemmed from a mix-up between sets as the objects being 'talked about' in a given language and sets as the universes of models of a sentence.

Comment: @Sho basically beeing finite or infinite isn't definiable within first order logci so we can't make formula which describes beeing (in)finite besides model understanding of beeing (in)finite.